# Why does the int field in the current node is the same as the string field at the next node in linked lists?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I am writing a program that uses linked lists to save information, this is the definition of the struct in a header file.

**structures.h:**

```c
typedef struct node* symbolPtr;

/* this will represent a member in the symbol table */
typedef struct node {
    char name[32];
    int address;
    
    symbolPtr next;
} Symbol;
```

And I noticed that the address of the 'address' field is the same as the address of the 'name' field in the next node, and I don't understand why.

This is the main file
**assembler.c:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "structures.h"


int firstRound(FILE*, symbolPtr, int*, int*);

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    int i;
    int *IC, *DC;
    symbolPtr smblTable;
    
    IC = malloc(sizeof(int));
    DC = malloc(sizeof(int));
    
    smblTable = malloc(sizeof(Symbol));
    
    smblTable->name[0] = '\0';
    smblTable->next = NULL;
    
    
    file = fopen("a.as", "r");
        
    

    firstRound(file, smblTable, IC, DC);
    
    free(IC);
    free(DC);
    free(smblTable);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the file where the problem happens, **firstMove.c:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "structures.h"

static int addToSmblTable(char*, symbolPtr, int);
static void printAd(symbolPtr smblTable);

int firstRound(FILE *file, symbolPtr smblTable, int *IC, int *DC) {
    char checker[32];
    
    *IC = 100, *DC = 0;

    /* this will go until we reach the end of the file */
    for (; !feof(file);) {
        fscanf(file, "%s", checker);
        
        addToSmblTable(checker, smblTable, *DC);//this saves the value of *DC in the node
        (*DC)++;
    }
    
    printAd(smblTable);// prints all the values of the linked list at the end
    
    return 0;
}

static void printAd(symbolPtr smblTable) {
    symbolPtr node;
    
    for (node = smblTable; node->next; node = node->next) {
        printf("\n%s:   %p  %p  %d\n", node->name, node->next->name, &(node->address), node->address);
//prints the string, the address of the next string and the address of the current 'address' field.
    }
}


static symbolPtr getLastNode(char *, symbolPtr);


static int addToSmblTable(char *symbol, symbolPtr table, int address) {
    symbolPtr node;
    
    
    
    node = getLastNode(symbol, table);//the last node
    
    if (node->name[0] != '\0') {
        node->next = malloc(sizeof(symbol));
        node = node->next;
    }
    
    /* saving the symbol */
    
    strcpy(node->name, symbol);//here the address of the last node is being changed
    node->address = address;
    
    
    
    node->next = NULL;
    
    
    return 0;
}


static symbolPtr getLastNode(char *symbol, symbolPtr table) {
    symbolPtr node;
    
    /* going over the symbol table and checking for the symbol */
    node = table; 
    while (node->next) {
        node = node->next;
    }
    
    return node;
}
```

This is the **makefile:**

```
test: assembler.o firstMove.o syntax.h structures.h
    gcc -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic assembler.o firstMove.o -o test

assembler.o: assembler.c structures.h
    gcc -c -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic assembler.c -o assembler.o

firstMove.o: firstMove.c structures.h
    gcc -c -g -ansi -Wall -pedantic firstMove.c -o firstMove.o
```

lets say this is **a.as:**

```
;file

;sample

.entry

.extern 

STR:

MAIN:

LOOP:

la

jmp

Next:

LIST:

bgt

la

sw

bne

call

jmp

la

.extern

.dh

K:

END:

.entry
```

Then this is the output:

```
In file a.as:

;file:  0x5566c6197920  0x5566c6196300  0

;sample:    0x5566c6197940  0x5566c6197940  1953391918

.entry: 0x5566c6197960  0x5566c6197960  1954047278

.extern:    0x5566c6197980  0x5566c6197980  978474067

STR::   0x5566c61979a0  0x5566c61979a0  1313423693

MAIN::  0x5566c61979c0  0x5566c61979c0  1347374924

LOOP::  0x5566c61979e0  0x5566c61979e0  24940

la: 0x5566c6197a00  0x5566c6197a00  7368042

jmp:    0x5566c6197a20  0x5566c6197a20  1954047310

Next::  0x5566c6197a40  0x5566c6197a40  1414744396

LIST::  0x5566c6197a60  0x5566c6197a60  7628642

bgt:    0x5566c6197a80  0x5566c6197a80  24940

la: 0x5566c6197aa0  0x5566c6197aa0  30579

sw: 0x5566c6197ac0  0x5566c6197ac0  6647394

bne:    0x5566c6197ae0  0x5566c6197ae0  1819042147

call:   0x5566c6197b00  0x5566c6197b00  7368042

jmp:    0x5566c6197b20  0x5566c6197b20  24940

la: 0x5566c6197b40  0x5566c6197b40  1954047278

.extern:    0x5566c6197b60  0x5566c6197b60  6841390

.dh:    0x5566c6197b80  0x5566c6197b80  14923

K:: 0x5566c6197ba0  0x5566c6197ba0  977555013

END::   0x5566c6197bc0  0x5566c6197bc0  1953391918

.entry: 0x5566c6197be0  0x5566c6197be0  1953391918
```

And you can see that the address of each 'address' field is the same as the address of the 'name' field in the next node.

Why is that? Am I not allocating the struct memory correctly?

Comment: OT: Pointer typedef is just a big no go IMO

Comment: OT: Don't cast `malloc`

Comment: `a.as` !? hmmm..

Comment: `printf("\nIn file %s:\n", argv[i]);` hmm... uninitialized `i`

Comment: You want to read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/4386427

Comment: `while (fgetc(file) != '\n' && !feof(file));` <<-- Huh?

Comment: `fopen(a.as, "r");` I wonder if you mean `fopen("a.as", "r");`

Comment: Thanks for your help but what i am asking is why are the addresses the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what this is doing

```
node->next = malloc(sizeof(symbol));
```

How many bytes is allocated here? What is `symbol` ?

Okay:

```
static int addToSmblTable(char *symbol, symbolPtr table, int address) {
    symbolPtr node;
    
    node = getLastNode(symbol, table);//the last node
    
    if (node->name[0] != '\0') {
        node->next = malloc(sizeof(symbol));
```

so `symbol` is a `char*`. Are you sure that you want to allocate memory for a char pointer?

Could this be a simple typo? `symbol` -> `Symbol`

A better way would be:

```
node->next = malloc(sizeof *(node->next));
```

Comment: 32 + size of int?

Comment: @SagiSason Read the last line of the answer again

Comment: @SagiSason `symbol` versus `Symbol`

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe it was this typo this whole time....

Comment: @SagiSason I can't believe you decided to give a char-pointer the name `symbol`. It's not a `Symbol` - it's a text string. So call it what it is and avoid simple typos ;-)

Comment: `node->next = malloc(sizeof (Symbol));`


wouldn't be enough? it worked for me

Comment: @SagiSason It's fine. I just prefer the other form to avoid typos ;-)